# Create a div by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like **create a div by clicking on a button** wich contains a form. Each div (form) contains informations about one plane. When I click on the save button, **each plane is saved** in the database. I've begun to realize the form but I don't know how to add these divs by clicking on a button. I've tried to use `$( ".div_avion" ).clone().appendTo( "#div_flotte" );` but it multiply the divs (not add).

This is the beginning of my code :

```
<div id="flotte" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Gestion de la flotte</h3><hr>
    <form action="<?php echo $CurrentURL;?>" method="POST">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];?>/administration/hubs/gerer"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Retour</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="button" value="saveflotte"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Enregistrer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="AddAvion()" class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Ajouter un appareil</button><hr>
    <div id="div_flotte">
    <div class="div_avion" style="width:300px;float:left;position:relative;margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="input-group" style="width:200px">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">F-BEN</span>
                  <input type="text" name="avions[][immat]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : 49" >
              </div>
              <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" name="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Marque</span>
                  <input type="text" name="avions[][marque]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : Airbus" >
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Modèle</span>
                 <input type="text" name="avions[][modele]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : 737" >
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">IATA</span>
                  <input type="text" name="avions[][iata]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : 738" >
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Type de vol</span>
                  <select name="avions[][type]" class="form-control-inline">
                    <?php
                      foreach ($types_vol_avion as $cle => $value) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$cle.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                        }
                      ?>
                </select>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Transport</span>
                  <select name="avions[][activite]" class="form-control-inline">
                    <?php
                      foreach ($Activite_avion as $cle => $value) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$cle.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                        }
                      ?>
                </select>
              </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    function AddAvion()
    {
        $( ".div_avion" ).clone().appendTo( "#div_flotte" );
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .eq function and get only the first div of class

```
$( ".div_avion" ).eq(0).clone().appendTo( "#div_flotte" );
```

Comment: Okay that's work for me but do you know if I can have a specific id or whatever on each div because I've also a delete button to remove it. I would also know if it's possible to change display property when I clone the div ?

Comment: if i undersend your needs, you can put the value of clone into variable on document ready and append to div clicking on the button.
Example `var clone=$( ".div_avion" ).eq(0).clone(); clone.appendTo("#div_flotte");`

Comment: Yes I would use the div with the class 'div_avion' like a variable and then clone it by adding an id or whatever to identify it if I want to remove it for example.

Comment: You can add a custom id maybe with numeric value  `$( ".div_avion" ).eq(0).clone().attr('id','div_avion'+($(".div_avion").length+1))`

Comment: Exactly what I want! I've changed the code to that : `$( ".div_avion" ).eq(0).clone().attr({id:'div_avion'+($(".div_avion").length+1), style:'display:visible;'}).css('display', 'visible').appendTo( "#div_flotte" );` thx

Answer (score 1):

Yeah `$( ".div_avion" ).clone().appendTo( "#div_flotte" );` should work. The problem is that you are selecting a div with a class (Use id instead b/c your guaranteed only one unique instance). Second, the div that you are selecting contains other child divs inside of it (that's why it multiplying). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple example using query http://jsfiddle.net/4dEsJ/1/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button[name='addDom']").click(function() {
            var domElement = $('<div class="module_holder"><div class="module_item"><img src="images/i-5.png" alt="Sweep Stakes" /></div></div>'); 
            $(this).after(domElement);
        });
   });
```

Comment: It's a good idea but it will be strong to have all my html code in this variable. I would prefer clone a hidden div and display the clone by using `display:visible`.